# Android App Crashing Before onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created an app that works fine on emulator ( API 25, API  19 ) and on a device ( API 23 ). However, when I try to run the same app on a KitKat device with API 19, app crashes.

I have created an abstract base activity that all other activities extend.

```
public abstract class BaseAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Typeface OPEN_SANS_REGULAR = null;

    private Typeface getOpenSans() {
        if ( OPEN_SANS_REGULAR == null ) {
            OPEN_SANS_REGULAR = Typeface.createFromAsset( this.getAssets(), FontConstants.OPEN_SANS_REGULAR );
        }

        return OPEN_SANS_REGULAR;
    }

    /**
     * Set text to open Sans.
     *
     * @param view
     */
    protected void useOpenSans( TextView view ) {
        if ( OPEN_SANS_REGULAR == null ) {
            OPEN_SANS_REGULAR = Typeface.createFromAsset( this.getAssets(), FontConstants.OPEN_SANS_REGULAR );
        }

        if ( null != OPEN_SANS_REGULAR ) {
            view.setTypeface( OPEN_SANS_REGULAR );
        }
    }

    protected void useOpenSans( TextView... views ) {
        if ( OPEN_SANS_REGULAR == null ) {
            OPEN_SANS_REGULAR = Typeface.createFromAsset( this.getAssets(), FontConstants.OPEN_SANS_REGULAR );
        }

        if ( null != OPEN_SANS_REGULAR ) {

            for ( TextView view : views ) {
                view.setTypeface( OPEN_SANS_REGULAR );
            }
        }
    }

    protected void useOpenSans( MenuItem item ) {
        if( item != null ) {
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());
            spannableString.setSpan(new OpenSansTypefaceSpan(getOpenSans()), 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            item.setTitle(spannableString);
        }
    }

    protected void useOpenSans( SubMenu menus ) {

        if( menus != null ) {
            int size = menus.size(), i = 0;

            for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
                useOpenSans( menus.getItem( i ) );
            }
        }
    }

    protected void useOpenSans( Menu menus ) {
        int size = menus.size(), i=0;

        for( i=0; i<size; i++ ) {
            MenuItem item =  menus.getItem( i );

            if( item != null ) {
                useOpenSans( item );
                useOpenSans( item.getSubMenu() );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransitionExit();
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity( Intent intent ) {
        super.startActivity( intent );
        overridePendingTransitionEnter();
    }

    /**
     * Overrides the pending Activity transition by performing the "Enter" animation.
     */
    protected void overridePendingTransitionEnter() {
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left );
    }

    /**
     * Overrides the pending Activity transition by performing the "Exit" animation.
     */
    protected void overridePendingTransitionExit() {
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right );
    }

    public abstract String getTag();

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransitionExit();
    }

    /**
     * Wrapped On Create.
     * This is done to ensure that a mail is sent whenever an exception occurs.
     */
    public abstract void wrappedOnCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState );

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        try{
            wrappedOnCreate( savedInstanceState );

        } catch ( Exception ex ){
            Log.e( getTag(), "Caught Exception ex " + ex.getMessage(), ex );
            Email email = new Email();

            String subject = "Caught Exception ex " + ex.getClass().getName() + " with message " + ex.getMessage();
            String body = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace( ex );

            email.setSubject( subject )
                    .setBody( body );

            Mailer.send( email );
        }
    }
}
```

All activities extending this `BaseAppCompactActivity` do not override `onCreate`, instead they all implement an `wrappedOnCreate` which is surrounded by a try catch block that sends mail if exception occurs. It has been tested on emulators and an Asus device, mailer do work.

However, on an HTC device ( API 19 ) HTC Desire 816G, app crashes with no email triggering. I can't not pull up this device to connect it to Android Monitor to view LogCat.

As I can see, since there is no e-mail triggered, it means android encounters a error before even being able to call onCreate or wrappedOnCreate ?

What may-be causing this ?

Comment: Post your crash report

Comment: I am not able to get my hands on one. I can't connect it to my android dev machine. I have tried aLogCat, and many other log apps, again not able to find any log.

Comment: You can't find problem without crash report. If you can't connect to you computer then use some Crash reporting library eg: Firebase Crash Reports or Crashlytics

Comment: @Sharj : I have just integrated Crashlytics. Let's see what it has in store. Any idea why email tracking might not work ?